# C# - Scheduling multiple operations in windows service without timer

Tags: c#, windows-services

I need to write a windows service which performs several operations as follows:

- Fetching data from api and dump it to db - to be performed every hour
- Consolidation - to be performed every 6 hours
- Summary - to be performed once a day at 01:00

I don't want to use multiple timers or no timer at all. Please suggest best way to schedule these tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. If you insist on using a windows service, you could look into Hangfire. The cost for using this is that you'll need to add a database that can store the information about the jobs.

Check the following link for Hangfire: https://www.hangfire.io/

You can also use the native Windows Scheduler for scheduling jobs.
Instead of creating a windows service you'll create a console app or something similar and use the Windows Scheduler for when it should execute.

If you don't want to use the native functionality I recommend using a nuget package like this one; https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

All the above was found with a little bit of google magic and knowing the windows operating system..

Comment: Quartz scheduler seems good and easy to start with. will try it first. thanks